# Microservices and jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-cloud

I like the idea of microservices and think that  I understand the basic idea.

I want to make a System of microservices, where each service is a seperate spring-boot project. 
For Example with two services, `Service-A` and `Service-B`. B has some JPA Entities and `A` makes a Request with `RestTemplate` to `B`.

`RestTemplate.getForObject(...)`needs the Class Type it should return. So must I also include the entities classes in the `Service-A` (seperate project) or is there a better way to send the Values of the Entities to other services.

I hope I did explain good enough my problem.

Comment: Hi Throum, Welcome to stack overflow, could you post the code so I would be helpful for understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen two ways to handle this:

1) Common library defining shared complex types - You have a project for Service A and a project for Service B, you also need a project for lib-alpha, maybe another project for lib-beta, etc. This would be a Java implementation of domain-specific complex types that multiple services could leverage

2) Craft a well-documented API and leave it up to the consumers to fend for themselves - This usually involved defining a high-level data encoding scheme (using XML, JSON, etc) and serializing data in Service A before sending data  needed to the API provider which then deserializes it on receipt

Comment: Shared code is exactly not what you want to do in a microservice though. The whole point is to make them completely isolated. What you describe here is more what you would do in a regular SOA system.

Comment: The thing is, we use shared code in microservices all the time, we just use common libraries that are provided by the community. I find that in large scale, domain-driven microservices architectures, identifying a shared library for something like cross-cutting data structures is within the scope of solution design.

Comment: That isn't a fair comparison; the third party library does not house your internally defined model. Changes to it are much less likely to cause conflicts.

Comment: Microservices should be split along the boundaries of the bounded contexts that you identify in your business domain. The need of a shared library is a sign you didn't get that split right.

Comment: I disagree @user625488. Cross-cutting concerns exist. The existence of cross-cutting concerns does not mean that the entirety of the business domain is a single-bounded context. You must have a mechanism for modeling cross-cutting concerns whether that be data, algorithms, or i/o.

Comment: @AlVaz can you give some examples? Usually, the cross-cutting concerns (that I'm aware of) are not business domain related. It's absolutely OK to use shared libs for those. But, with microservices, there's no problem if you solve those non-business-related concerns differently in each microservice.

Comment: @user625488 I believe a concrete example might be sales/client orders entities, which could be accessed by a price optimization service, a sales report service, a financial ledger service, etc. The domain seggregation constraint would require the replication of the sales database, one version of it for each microservice. We could substitute entities for views, thus maintaining implementation independence and keeping the single database, but as far as I know this would invalidate the use of JPA